# I need to combine 2 queries but need to sum some part of them

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that will output 2 columns each. They're from the same table.

Query 1

```
SELECT MONTH(DateOrdered) AS MONTH,SUM(Downpayment)AS total FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(DateOrdered) = YEAR('2018-12-00') AND Status = 'Ongoing' GROUP BY MONTH(DateOrdered)


MONTH-----total

10------------4590

12------------1497.5
```

Query 2

```
SELECT MONTH(DateFinish) AS MONTH,SUM(Total-Downpayment)AS total FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(DateFinish) = YEAR('2018-12-00') AND Status = 'Complete' GROUP BY MONTH(DateFinish)


MONTH--------total

5-----------------1147.5

10----------------1647

12----------------1147.5
```

I want to combine the two and SUM The 2 columns named total

For Example

```
MONTH------------total

5--------------------1147.5

10--------------------6237

12--------------------2645
```

What I have right now

```
SELECT MONTH(DateOrdered) AS MONTH,SUM(Downpayment) FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(DateOrdered) = YEAR('2018-12-00') AND Status = 'Ongoing' GROUP BY MONTH(DateOrdered) UNION SELECT MONTH(DateFinish) AS MONTH,SUM(Total-Downpayment) FROM transaction WHERE YEAR(DateFinish) = YEAR('2018-12-00') AND Status = 'Complete' GROUP BY MONTH(DateFinish)
```

it Shows

```
MONTH--------total

10----------------4590

12----------------1497.5

5-----------------1147.5

10----------------1647

12----------------1147.5
```

Comment: That's a *requirement*; do you have a *question*? Have you attempted this yourself? What happened?

Comment: I've tried using UNION but I cant think of a way to sum the total of the columns that have the same data(MONTH)

Comment: Then put a [mcve] in the question

Comment: Will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced concepts to use here are: 1) Union query and 2) subquery

It would look something like the following:

```
Select 
    sum(total) as totalByMonth,
    month
from
(
    SELECT 
        MONTH(DateOrdered) AS MONTH,
        SUM(Downpayment)AS total 
    FROM 
        transaction 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(DateOrdered) = YEAR('2018-12-00') 
        AND Status = 'Ongoing' 
    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(DateOrdered)

    Union

    SELECT 
        MONTH(DateFinish) AS MONTH,
        SUM(Total-Downpayment)AS total 
    FROM 
        transaction 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(DateFinish) = YEAR('2018-12-00') 
        AND Status = 'Complete' 
    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(DateFinish)

) subQuery1

group by
    month
```

Comment: I tried your query sir and it works like a charm! Thank you for the help! :)